# Is subjunctive usage justified here?

Tags: grammaticality, subject-verb-agreement

Context: One (younger one) of the father's sons furtively watches his dad trying to do a mediocre enough back flip but he generally never ever has tried doing it, couple of seconds later his older brother passes by him, so would the first son say the following statement to his big brother when big brother asks him what he is doing?

"Watch our father DO a backflip"

I'm not fully sure if "DO" indicates infinitive or subjunctive. A detailed explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: The quality of the backflip and the age of the sons have nothing to do with it. He would probably say "I'm watching Dad do (or doing) a backflip." The subjunctive would be something like "If Dad were to do a really good backflip, I'd be very proud of him."